# To color the two regions separated by a parabolic function with different colors respectively using tikz (The function as the boundary)

Tags: tikz

Could someone give some suggestions? I want to color the two areas of the rectangle with blue and yellow respectively, as shown in the picture. The function is as the boundary between the two regions.

Here is my code and expected result.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[shorten >=1pt,-,draw=black!80, node distance=\layersep]      
    
     \begin{axis}[
            width=8.8cm,
            enlargelimits=false,
            axis on top,    
            point meta=explicit,
            height=6.5cm, 
            xlabel={},
            ylabel={},
            xtick=\empty,
            ytick=\empty,       
            xmin=-8,
            xmax=8,
            ymin=-10,
            ymax=1,
            xlabel={\large $x$},
            ylabel={\large $y$},
            %ylabel style={yshift=0.0cm},
            yticklabels={},
            xticklabel style = {font=\large,yshift=0.0ex},         
            colorbar style={
                 font =\Large
            },
        ]
        \addplot [thick]{-0.8*(x-1)^2};

        \end{axis}
    \end{scope}
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[shorten >=1pt,-,draw=black!80, node distance=\layersep]      
    
     \begin{axis}[
            width=8.8cm,
            enlargelimits=false,
            axis on top,    
            point meta=explicit,
            height=6.5cm, 
            xlabel={},
            ylabel={},
            xtick=\empty,
            ytick=\empty,       
            xmin=-8,
            xmax=8,
            ymin=-10,
            ymax=1,
            xlabel={\large $x$},
            ylabel={\large $y$},
            %ylabel style={yshift=0.0cm},
            yticklabels={},
            xticklabel style = {font=\large,yshift=0.0ex},         
            colorbar style={
                 font =\Large
            },
            axis background/.style={fill=yellow},
        ]
        
        \addplot [thick,fill=blue]{-0.8*(x-1)^2};

        \end{axis}
    \end{scope}
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]